# How to set the concentric circle layout parameters in python dash_cytoscape?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, cytoscape

I have my elements defined like where level refers to the circle layer I want that node.

```
 elements = [{'data': {'id': 'a', 'label': 'a', 'level': 1},
             {'data': {'id': 'b', 'label': 'b', 'level': 1},
             {'data': {'id': 'c', 'label': 'c', 'level': 2},
             .......]
```

I have tried the following which doesnt work (error loading layout)

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    cyto.Cytoscape(
        id='cytoscape',
        elements= elements,
        layout={'name': 'concentric', 'concentric': lambda x: x['data']['level']}
    )
])
```

The javascript documentation is here https://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts and specifies

```
let options = {
  name: 'concentric',
  concentric: function( node ){ // returns numeric value for each node, placing higher nodes in levels towards the centre
  return node.degree();
  }
```

How do I set this concentric parameter?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's not possible to pass python functions to the `layout` parameter in a `cyto.Cytoscape` component. This is because the function will not be transpiled to a JS function, which is what is needed for the `concentric` key to work inside `options`.

Alternatives would be:

1. Use a python network library (e.g. networkX) to assign the x/y positions based on the concentric algorithm, then return the exact position using a custom layout in dash-cytoscape (rather than a concentric layout).
2. Modify the source code of `cyto.Cytoscape` and hard code the JS `function` you'd like to use for the concentric layout. You'd need to follow the contributing instructions to build and create a custom installation.